# "power of persuasion" (singular) vs. "powers of persuasion" (plural)

Tags: expressions, idioms, grammatical-number, variants

Which one would you say is correct and why?

[1] "power of persuasion" (singular)

[2] "powers of persuasion" (plural)

Newspapers and books seem to use both alternatives.

Merriam-Webster includes both alternatives https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/power(s)%20of%20persuasion

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason to suppose that only one is correct?

Comment: Interesting question. This appears to be an instance where variant versions of a set phrase have coexisted for centuries. [Here is the Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=power+of+persuasion%2C+powers+of+persuasion&year_start=1600&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) for "power of persuasion" (blue line) versus "powers of persuasion" (red line) for the period 1600–2019.

Comment: So both variants are ok with the "s" version being more frequently used?

Comment: It's Merriam. Also, if you found both expressions in newspapers and dictionaries, where does your doubt lie?

Comment: You can have one power or many powers. It's sufficiently vague that it's not clear what applies in many cases. Unless you are discussing a particular power (e.g. gift of the gab, or the ability to shoot people who disagree with you), it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

They're probably interchangeable in general, but I think the singular form refers to a general ability to persuade, while the plural form refers to a number of different techniques (flattery, coercion, bribery, etc.) that are used to persuade. But it's non-specific, so it's still not clear which of these someone in particular actually uses.

Comment: The problem that I see is that, more often than not, a general singular power of persuasion involves a plurality of "subpowers" of persuasion (i.e., a persuasive person can be manipulative, seductive, etc.).

Comment: That's what I'm saying. When you have the power of persuasion, it means you have a collection of powers.